# How to access a single information in xml

Tags: python, xml, python-3.5

currently I am trying to modify an xml from data in csv. To do that I am accessing the data inside the csv with a pandas dataframe. I want to access also single information from the xml and overwrite the data in the xml with the data in the csv.

So I wrote the funtions for the csv but I dont know how  to access the xml data so if anyone can help me that would be really cool.

```
        <Test Testbench="3" Result="PASSED" Name="8">
            <SubTests>
                <SubTest Result="PASSED" Name="8_1">
                    <Measurement Name="U5" Type="Number">
                        <Number>
                            <Value>9.300001</Value>
                            <Unit>V</Unit>
                        </Number>
                    </Measurement>
                </SubTest>
                <SubTest Result="PASSED" Name="8_2">
                    <Measurement Name="U6" Type="Number">
                        <Number>
                            <Value>3.099975</Value>
                            <Unit>V</Unit>
                        </Number>
                    </Measurement>
                </SubTest>
                <SubTest Result="PASSED" Name="8_3">
                    <Measurement Name="U7" Type="Number">
                        <Number>
                            <Value>11.500010</Value>
                            <Unit>V</Unit>
                        </Number>
                    </Measurement>
                </SubTest>
                <SubTest Result="PASSED" Name="8_4">
                    <Measurement Name="U8" Type="Number">
                        <Number>
                            <Value>3.199975</Value>
                            <Unit>V</Unit>
                        </Number>
                    </Measurement>
                </SubTest>
            </SubTests>
        </Test>
```

How can I access for example the 3.199975 Value in the xml

I want to save an output like this.

```
print(Function)

3.199975
```

Comment: parse xml and search by Name attribute

Comment: do you suggest element.tree or minidom

Answer (score 0):

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


root = ET.fromstring(x) # or ET.parse(file_path) if loading from a file

# prints 3.199975, searching by Measurement's Name attribute
print(root.findall(".//Measurement[@Name='U8']/Number/Value")[0].text)

# get all values in a list
print([i.text for i in root.findall(".//Measurement/Number/Value")])
```